# pycparser visit else only of an if-else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycparser

I'm using pycparser to parse some C code. Specifically, I need certain portions of the code, included in pycparser are some visitors like **visit_If** to visit **"If"** sections of the code. However, I'm having problem visiting **'else'** part of an if-else statement.

Example 1:

```
if (x == 0)
{
    // some statements
}
else
{
    // some statements -> I only need all codes under else
}
```

Example 2:

```
if (x == 0)
    // a statement
else
    // a statement -> I only need all codes under else
```

How is this possible in pycparser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `If` node has an `iffalse` child node which is the `else` clause from the original code. For example, [see the C code generator](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_generator.py#L210) (part of `pycparser`):

```
def visit_If(self, n):
    s = 'if ('
    if n.cond: s += self.visit(n.cond)
    s += ')\n'
    s += self._generate_stmt(n.iftrue, add_indent=True)
    if n.iffalse:
        s += self._make_indent() + 'else\n'
        s += self._generate_stmt(n.iffalse, add_indent=True)
    return s
```

This is a good example of visiting an `If` node and accessing all its child nodes.

Comment: I would also like to ask know how to get the line number of "else" line.  I know its in coord.line but iffalse coord.line of example 1 points to "{". Is there a way?

Comment: @Thor, It should point to the right place. This could be a bug so please open a Github issue with a minimal reproducer

Comment: Accepted answer. I added a github issue